# put is not applicable for HashMap type

Tags: java, hashmap

Below is my code snippet

```
Map<Object, Object> gobalMap = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> mp = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Integer>>();
gobalMap.put("mp",mp );


((Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>)gobalMap.get("mp")).put("A", new HashMap<String, Integer>().put("A", 1));
```

error:

```
The method put(String, Map<String,Integer>) in the type Map<String,Map<String,Integer>> is not applicable for the arguments (String, Integer)
```

May I know where am doing wrong ..?

Comment: `new HashMap<String, Integer>().put("A", 1)` returns an integer. As such it cannot be the value in a `Map<String,Map<String,Integer>>`.

Comment: @khelwood, but value of mp is HashMap..No .. ? why new HashMap<String, Integer>().put("A", 1) returns Integer ?

Comment: @khelwood, then what's wrong into that ..!

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @JennyRose what version of Java do you use?

Answer (score 2):

```
new HashMap<String, Integer>().put("A", 1)
```

This returns an Integer. But you want to add this to an object which stores Maps and not Integer. So that's not possible. Also as Thomas explained in the comments, your code would not work even if it compiled because `put` returns the *previous* value of the map so you will receive a `NullPointerException`.

I would recommend restructuring your code to make it more readable and to also make it work:

```
    Map<Object, Object> gobalMap = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
    Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> mp = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Integer>>();
    gobalMap.put("mp",mp );
    HashMap<String, Integer> aMap = new HashMap<>();
    aMap.put("A", 1);
    ((Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>)gobalMap.get("mp")).put("A", aMap);
```

Comment: But why I cant use put inside a put. If am putting map inside map..then it should be done the way am doing ..? I'm confused here..!

Comment: Just check what the second put returns. It returns an Integer. But you cannot put an integer into your map of maps.

Comment: @JennyRose I've updated my answer. This should be clearer now

Comment: What's significance of returning Integer ..? Is it correct ..?

Comment: Note that `put()` returns the _previous_ value so if there wasn't a value for key `"A"` yet that `put("A", ...).put("A",1)` will cause a NPE.

Comment: @Thomas I've added your information to the answer. Did not know that. Funny that that's how it's handled...

Comment: Well it's actually not that surprising or funny :) - It's a convenient way to check what as been replaced by the new value (which you know anyway). The map methods (and those in the other "collections") aren't meant to support chaining like that (except for some of the newly added default methods).

Answer (score 1):

As others have already stated `new HashMap<String, Integer>().put("A", 1)` returns an `Integer` (the previously mapped value for key `"A"` so `null` in this case) and that is not a suitable value for a `Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>`.

You're creating a suitable map but don't actually put it into the map so the reference to that map is lost.

Since you're probably trying to only create a nested map if it doesn't exist already try this:

```
((Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>)gobalMap.get("mp"))
         .computeIfAbsent( "A", k -> new HashMap<String, Integer>())
         .put("A", 1);
```

This does the following:

1. get and cast the map from `globalMap` (if you'd not be sure this can't return `null` you could use `computeIfAbsent()` here as well)
2. get the nested map for key `"A"` and if it doesn't exist create a new one, add and return it
3. put the value `1` for key `"A"` into the nested map

Answer (score 0):

`new HashMap<String, Integer>().put("A", 1)` returns an integer, because when you `put` into a hashmap, you get back the previous value held by that key. As such it cannot be the value in a `Map<String,Map<String,Integer>>`.

Perhaps you meant to cast `gobalMap` to a `Map<String,Map<String,Integer>>`. But you are actually casting `gobalMap.get("mp")` to a `Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>`.

This, on the other hand, would compile:

```
((Map<String, Integer>) gobalMap.get("mp")).put("A", new HashMap<String, Integer>().put("A", 1));
```

though I'm not sure it does anything useful.

Comment: But gobalMap.put("mp",mp ) should returns Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> ..Noo..?

Answer (score 0):

you missed the bracket. correct code will be:

```
((Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>)gobalMap.get("mp")).put("A", new HashMap<String, Integer>()).put("A", 1);
```